# Can I revive dead party members?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

My brave Minotaur just died. Is there a way to revive him, or do I have to load an older save? Waiting doesn't seem to make him any less dead.

Comment: I haven't tested it out, but from the description I think those glowy floaty crystals will revive dead party members - the scroll you find near the first one says they'll "restore health and restore life", IIRC.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I just checked it out. The glowing blue crystals *do* bring your members back to life.

[image: resurrection stones]

Comment: You are right, at the moment it seems there is not other way to revive a party member. I added a screenshot.

Comment: Great, I was just wondering if there was a way to revive and good old StackExchanged had the answer! :)

Comment: Wow the game doesn't communicate that very well, I've just been reloading when a character dies.

Comment: @JamesMcMahon yeah, the manual is not that great at explaining some of the in-game mechanics :/

Comment: That's on purpose, the not explaining things well... It's all about you figuring it out. Classic Rogue-like cliches.